# best process for checking browser

Tags: regex

In the process of writing a regex to obtain the browser and version. This is what I have so far. Can anyone advise a better process? The regex will check for IE/Firefox/Safari/Chrome from this I can check the version number.

```
import flashx.textLayout.formats.BackgroundColor;

var inputField:TextField = new TextField();
var displayField:TextField = new TextField();

// RegExp 
var reg:RegExp = /(MSIE|(?!Gecko.+)Firefox|(?!AppleWebKit.+Chrome.+)Safari|(?!AppleWebKit.+)Chrome|AppleWebKit(?!.+Chrome|.+Safari)|Gecko(?!.+Firefox)   (SeaMonkey))(?: |\/)([\d]+)/i;

inputField.border = true;
inputField.width = 500;
inputField.height = 50;
inputField.x = 75;
inputField.y = 50;
inputField.type = "input";
inputField.multiline = true;
addChild(inputField);

displayField.border = true;
displayField.width = 500;
displayField.height = 200;
displayField.backgroundColor = 0x666666;
displayField.x = 75;
displayField.y = inputField.y + 50 + inputField.height;
displayField.multiline = true;
addChild(displayField);

inputField.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeListener, false, 0, true);


function changeListener(event:Event):void
{
    var strToTest:String = inputField.text;
    var textToDisplay:String = "";
    if(reg.test(strToTest))
    {
        var browser:String = strToTest.match(reg)[1];
        var version:int = strToTest.match(reg)[2];

        var chromeVersion:int = 29;
        var firefoxVersion:int = 23;
        var ieVersion:int = 7;
        var safariVersion:int = 6;

        textToDisplay += "BROWSER IS " + browser;
        textToDisplay += "\nVersion " + version;


        if(browser == "Chrome")
        {
            if(version <= chromeVersion)
            {
                textToDisplay += "\nUPDATE CHROME - VERSION BELOW " +  chromeVersion;

            }
            else
            {

                textToDisplay += "\nVERSION GREATER THAN " + chromeVersion;
            }

        }
        else if(browser == "MSIE")
        {
            if(version <= ieVersion)
            {
                textToDisplay += "\nUPDATE CHROME - VERSION BELOW " + ieVersion;

            }
            else
            {

                textToDisplay += "\nVERSION GREATER THAN " + ieVersion;
            }

        }
        else if (browser == "Firefox")
        {
            if(version <= firefoxVersion)
            {
                textToDisplay += "\nUPDATE CHROME - VERSION BELOW " + firefoxVersion;

            }
            else
            {

                textToDisplay += "\nVERSION GREATER THAN " + firefoxVersion;
            }
        }
        else if (browser == "Safari")
        {
            if(version <= safariVersion)
            {
                textToDisplay += "\nUPDATE CHROME - VERSION BELOW " + safariVersion;

            }
            else
            {

                textToDisplay += "\nVERSION GREATER THAN " + safariVersion;
            }

        }






    }
    else
    {

        textToDisplay = "Browser is NOT IE/FIREFOX/SAFARI/CHROME"

    }

    displayField.text = textToDisplay;

}
```

Comment: There are dozens of libraries which are made for handling this kind of thing.

Comment: yeah I wouldn't endeavor to write and maintain this... but what problem are you seeing?

Comment: (MSIE|(?!Gecko.+)Firefox(?!.+SeaMonkey)|(?!AppleWebKit.+Chrome.+Safari.+)Version|(?!AppleWebKit.+)Chrome|AppleWebKit(?!.+Chrome|.+Safari))(?: |\/)([\d]+)

Answer (score 0):

(MSIE(?!.+Opera)|Firefox(?!.+SeaMonkey)|Version(?=.+Safari)(?!.+Chrome)|Chrome)(?: |/)([\d]+)

I Simplified the Regex to follow these checks https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent.

I don't want to use a third party lib as I would like to understand as I may need to make changes. The following code appears to be returning correctly for what I want.

(MSIE(?!.+Opera)|Firefox(?!.+SeaMonkey)|Version(?=.+Safari)(?!.+Chrome)|Chrome)(?: |/)([\d]+)